# how do I use Artemis with Camel Java DSL using the camel-jms component?

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis, jms2

Right now I'm using JMS 2.0 with Artemis 1.2.0 on a Java EE 7 application and I would like to do some integration tasks with Camel.

Right now checking the camel-jms documentation, there is no mention whatsoever on how to use the generic camel JMS component to produce and consume messages to any JMS 2.0 compliant broker.

The only example on [the component documentation](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) is configuring an ActiveMQ connection factory with its specialized ActiveMQ component using the Spring DSL. How can I configure a connection for Camel JMS to connect to my Artemis instance?

Take into account that even though Artemis is compatible with ActiveMQ 5.x, I'm going to use a Camel route to publish and subscribe to shared durable topics, so I need to be able to configure an Artemis connection and do a publisher and a shared durable subscriber with it (only supported in JMS 2.0, ActiveMQ only supports JMS 1.1).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In the end I just created an Artemis connection factory and I'm using camel-sjms, for JMS 2.0 features at the moment I just go straight to JMS 2.0 producers as a camel components, and for consumers I use the latest Spring Messaging which uses JMS 2.0

I hope that in the future, the camel-sjms module is updated for JMS 2.0 and that way I just use vanilla Camel instead of having to work around through custom components.

Comment: check [https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/sjms2-component.html](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/sjms2-component.html)